# I generated html code (lots of divs) with javascript. Now I want to find the generated divs with GetElementById

Tags: javascript, html, dom

GetElementById works if I manually added a div id="something" inside the body and use window.onload = init method in the script to get it. Works great.

But if I used a for loop to generate divs where id's is 1,2,3 and so on. I can't get it. Is there a way to get to those generated divs?

This is what generates the html code (just to be clear what I mean):

```
for(i=0; i<randomizeColoursList.length; i++)
{
    document.getElementById("renderColors").innerHTML += 
        '<div class=\"box\"><div class=\"' + i + '\"><font color=\"' 
        + randomizeColoursList[i] + '\">' 
        + "" + '<img src=\"dist/card_bg.gif\"></div></div>';                    
}
```

Generates one of these:

```
<div class="8"><font color="#3be6c4"><img src="dist/card_bg.gif"></font></div>
```

Div with class 8 is the id I want to get for example. But is says it's null.

Thanks.

Comment: Class is not an Id.  Can you explain what you believe the ID value is for the following tag `<div class="8">`? In addition if you are trying to set Ids to a numeric value it may work but not valid to specifications.  `ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").`

Comment: How do you expect `getElementById` to work when the elements don't have ids?

Comment: FYI, the ID's (and names) of HTML elements must start with a letter ... starting numeric will cause you issues in IE. Spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name {quote: ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")}

Comment: Omg.. Had a brain fart. Coded whole day and didn't see the class and id. So stupid. Sorry people. Googled for an hour and.... sorry. Thanks all for the quick reply. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `id` is *null* because you haven't specified it in your markup creation. Looks like you're assigning the `id` value to `class` instead.

Comment: id and class are not the same thing.

Comment: That's the thing. The div with id=8 is rendered but I can't get it. If I use document.getElementById("8") it says it's null.

Comment: You haven't specified `id`. You specified `class` which pertains to CSS. `class` is not `id`.

Comment: Ah thank you. Coded all day today and somehow missed that. Again thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generate something more like this:

```
<div id="div1" class="8"><font color="#3be6c4"><img src="dist/card_bg.gif"></font></div>
```

Also, you don't need to use font tags, nor should you use them. Just add the styling to the div.

```
<div id="div1" class="8" style="color:#3be6c4;"><img src="dist/card_bg.gif"></div>
```

Comment: There's no chance that `class="8"` is anything meaningful.

Comment: That is correct. class was supposed to be id. I don't know how my brain thought it was id to begin with.I use css but I just started with the a concept I'm trying to get to work. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: No worries. It happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're going about this is a little backwards. If you write your code like I have below, then you don't need to give the divs IDs, you end up with an array full of references to them anyway.

```
var i, div, img;
var createdDivs = [];
for(i=0; i<randomizeColoursList.length; i++)
{
    div = document.createElement('div');
    img = document.createElement('img');
    div.className = "box";
    div.style.backgroundColor = randomizeColoursList[i];
    div.style.color = randomizeColoursList[i];
    img.src = "dist/card_bg.gif"

    div.appendChild(img);
    document.getElementById("renderColours").appendChild(div);                

    createdDivs.push(div);
}
```

Live link: http://jsfiddle.net/7HjLL/

Comment: I'm making a color memory game with cards. Where I have to use the arrow keys and enter key only. If I have an id and name on the divs then I can use those to move around a highlight and select and compare cards. I must say your code is beautiful. I'm new to javascript, I just finished a java only education. I'll probably try this out to create those divs. Thanks you very much.

Comment: Learning how to do javascript properly is important so you don't develop too many bad habits. How are you planning on creating your game? You should be thinking about having a `Game` class, with a 2d array of cards. Each card should be of the `Card` class, and that class should hold the reference to the div. (Also don't use <font>, use css for that kind of thing)

Comment: I used the font just to test the colors. I never use font tag. I'll look up how to do classes in js. I didn't think javascript could do that. My plan was just to compare the name of the div and based on that just to remove the card image.

Comment: @user992013 I was feeling bored, so here is some stuff to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/Ebhzr/ It uses the mouse, but you can change that. And it's missing allll the logic (like only 2 cards of each colour, only 2 flipped, that sort of thing)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will study your code and implement the ideas to my project. Thanks.